# Unable to retrive file present inside docker container using subprocess module

Tags: python-3.x, docker, teamcity

I am running a container and trying to read a file content from another docker container using subprocess module. Everything run fine when I run in local container setup, but as soon as I run it on teamcity it gives error.

below is my code:

```
    docker_command = "docker ps -a"
    docker_command_output = subprocess.check_output(docker_command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print("docker_command output", docker_command_output)
    docker_container_id = "docker ps | grep graphite:10 | awk '{ print $1 }'"
    docker_container_id_output = subprocess.check_output(docker_container_id, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print("docker_container_id_output", docker_container_id_output)
    docker_container_id_output = docker_container_id_output.strip().decode("utf-8")
    read_storage_schema_cmd = "docker exec -it {} cat /usr/bin/graphithooks/graphite.conf".format(docker_container_id_output)
    print("read_storage_schema_cmd1", read_storage_schema_cmd)
    storage_schema = subprocess.check_output(read_storage_schema_cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Output :

```
docker_command output b'CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                  NAMES\nd003275a3728        graphite:10                                                                 "pid1 graphitehooks.\xe2\x80\xa6"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes 

[14:59:43][Step 1/2] docker_container_id_output b'd003275a3728\n'
[14:59:43][Step 1/2] read_storage_schema_cmd1 docker exec -it d003275a3728 cat /usr/bin/graphithooks/write-graphite-conf
[14:59:43][Step 1/2] Issue Command 'docker exec -it d003275a3728 cat /usr/bin/graphithooks/graphite-conf' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: It's probably better to use the [Docker Python SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) than to try to script `docker` CLI calls like this.  In particular, it's pretty straightforward to use `docker` commands to root the host, and the `read_storage_schema_cmd` isn't constructed in a safe way.

Comment: @DavidMaze what do you mean by safe way?

Comment: I'm going to set `docker_container_id_output = '; cat /etc/shadow; echo'`.  What happens when I try to run the resulting command?  (You should pretty much never use `subprocess.call(shell=True)` if it's at all avoidable.)